# CTE on team hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table of employees and managers.

```
create table hrc (
  id int, 
  employee varchar(255),
  manager varchar(255)
);

insert into hrc
values
(1, "A", Null),
(2, "B", "A"),
(3, "C", "B"),
(4, "D", "B"),
(5, "E", "C"),
(6, "E", "D"),
(7, "F", "C"),
(8, "G", "F"),
(9, "H", "E");
```

So a different thing about this table from all the hierarchy cte examples available out there is "an employee can have more than two managers".

I want to get all the employee in the hierarchy for "B". I have tried this but the below code but it did not work

```
with hierarchy as 
(
  select emp, 1 as lvl
  from hrc 
  where emp = 'B'
  
  union all
  
  select h.emp, lvl+1
  from hierarchy as h
  join hrc as t
  on h.emp = t.mang
)

select * from hierarchy
```

Expected result

B > CD > EF > GH

Comment: B > CD > EF > GH  I'm not sure your expected result is correct. How is G excluded?

Comment: First things first. What entity does this table represent? Employee, Manager, the relationship between them? The modeling seems wrong.

Comment: You are right @PaulMaxwell I made an edit

Comment: What kind of Sql is this? It's not Sql Server or MySql, what is it?

Comment: What's the primary key of the table?

Comment: Id is the primary key

Comment: "It did not work" does not describe the specific problem. Did you get an incorrect result? And you really do need to specify the dbms too, choose a tag for that.

Comment: What does B > CD > EF > GH mean? Do you want to return this exact string? Otherwise you need to specify exact result as a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to group all descendants that are the same distance away from the specified level together. That is, nodes C & D are distance 1 away from node B while nodes E & F are distance 2. Here's what I came up with:

```sql
with hierarchy as 
(
  select emp, mang, 1 as lvl
  from #hrc 
  where emp = 'B'
  
  union all
  
  select child.emp, parent.emp, lvl+1
  from hierarchy as parent
  join #hrc as child
      on child.mang = parent.emp
), lvls as (
    select lvl, emp
    from hierarchy
    group by lvl, emp
)
select lvl, STRING_AGG(emp, '') within group (order by emp)
from lvls
group by lvl;
```

By way of explanation, I only slightly modified your initial attempt by adding a manager column within the initial CTE to give me a way to join successive levels in the hierarchy. I also renamed the aliases for the base vs recursive elements to parent and child (respectively) as that helps me to keep straight which is which. From there, I did a simple `group by lvl` to get nodes that are eliminate duplicates. Lastly, I use `STRING_AGG` to concatenate all nodes at the same level together.

Comment: It's giving an error when I am trying to run it "Error: near "(": syntax error"

Comment: I just double checked and it runs against my local instance (mssql version 15.0.4280.7 fwiw). [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cb4039/1) is a SQL Fiddle showing it working on SQL 2017.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Though it is still giving error in my sql editor

Answer (score -2):

Using a recursive CTE is correct here. Though I don't fully understand your desired result, your should do something like this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hrc;

create table hrc (
  id int, 
  emp varchar(255),
  man varchar(255)
);

insert into hrc
values
(1, 'A', Null),
(2, 'B', 'A'),
(2, 'C', 'B'),
(2, 'D', 'B'),
(2, 'E', 'C'),
(2, 'E', 'D'),
(2, 'F', 'C'),
(2, 'G', 'F'),
(2, 'H', 'E');


with hierarchy as 
(
  select emp, 1 as lvl
  from hrc 
  where emp = 'B'
  
  union all
  
  select t.emp, lvl+1 as lvl

  from hierarchy as h
  inner join hrc as t
  on h.emp = t.man
)

select * from hierarchy
order by lvl
;
```